# Is Valgrind ignoring Trap Flag (TF) bit in RFLAGS register?

Tags: c, assembly, signals, valgrind, eflags

In one of my project I need to manually edit the RFLAGS register to raise a SIGTRAP upon each instruction using the TF bit. It works when running the program directly, but not when running it under Valgrind.

Here is a quick program that shows what I mean:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define REG_EFL 17
#define TRAP_FLAG 0x100

void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ctx) {
  const char msg[] = "From handler\n";
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
  ((ucontext_t*)ctx)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EFL] &= ~TRAP_FLAG;
}

int main() {
  struct sigaction act = {0};
  act.sa_sigaction = &handler;
  act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sigaction(SIGTRAP, &act, NULL);
  puts("Raising SIGTRAP 1");
  __asm__("pushfq;"
          "pop %rax;"
          "or $0x100, %rax;"
          "push %rax;"
          "popfq;");
  puts("Raising SIGTRAP 2");
  __asm__("int3;");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the expected output:

```
Raising SIGTRAP 1
From handler
Raising SIGTRAP 2
From handler
```

Here is the Valgrind output:

```
Raising SIGTRAP 1
Raising SIGTRAP 2
From handler
```

Comment: `puts` is not sigaction-safe. It is likely an UB.

Comment: `write(STDIN_FILENO,...);`?!?!?

Comment: Whoopsie I'm tired...

Comment: When using traps, it might be needed to use the valgrind option --vex-iropt-register-updates=allregs-at-each-insn

Comment: Sadly it did not change the behavior, but thanks!